# getting sqlconnection string arguments from method c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

Let us consider some methods

```
method1(argument 1, argument 2, argument 3)
{
    con.open();
    con.close();
}

method 2(argument 1,argument 2,argument 3,argument 4)
{
    con.open();
    con.close();
}

method 3(argument 1,argument 2)
{
    con.open();
    con.close();
}
```

the above three methods used to get argument which are necessary for connection such as [SqlCommand cmd, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans, CommandType cmdType]

all these methods are compiled as dll .

Now i need to create the project which scans the above method and return the output that which argument holds the connection string

Now my query is

1. how can we find which argument contains connection string in it?
2. As we all know that with out connection string con.open throws the error is there any way to find it through?

Waiting for your valuable suggestions and commands

**Edited**:

my ultimate solution is that i will be having a dll only with me my job is to scan the dll and find where the con.open method is present in it and finally i need to get parameters which are passed to that method to find where the connection string comes inside method

Comment: You question is not clear. Why do you need to get "arguments" from a connection-string? You should not create such helper methods. Instead use `using-statetement` wherever you create and use connections and other disposable objects like commands. Otherwise it's possible that connections stay open what could cause performance issues or errors.

Comment: You should know which argument (parameter) has the connection string in it because you should have them intelligently named. So what is your real question?

Comment: @slugster basically i will be having a dll only with me my job is to scan the dll and find where the con.open method is present in it and finally i need to get parameters which are passed to that method to find where the connection string comes inside method

Comment: @GrahamClark THATS ONLY I AM DOING NOW ... with out that is der any way

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
If( argument  is SqlConnection)
{

}
```

But if you have latest version of framework, you can use optinal and named parameters

Answer (score 0):

You're probabby sarching for [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7z89tex.aspx).

Where *parameter* is valid conections string. After that:

> Parsed into name/value pairs. Invalid key names raise
>   KeyNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do, please explain m not getting it.

but u can do

```
try
{
  con.open();
  con.close();
}
catch
{
  //show message
}
```

Comment: i am having dll only with me i do not know how the code is written inside it my job is to write generic program which scans everything and gives me which class the con.open is present and which arguments the connection string is given to that method

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the [method information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but that doesn't tell you which parameter is the connection string - it is simply a string after all. You could take an educated guess by checking the [name of the parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I'm not sure why you would need to do this though - the VS IDE intellisense will give you a lot of information when you write code that calls those methods.

Comment: i too retrived the method name where con.open is used through reflection only but my aim is to find the parameters passing to that method which contains connection string